# How can a variable have a value and also not be defined?

Tags: ruby, variables

I am trying to learn ruby, and have come across something strange. This code:

```
if defined? branch
    puts "param: #{branch}\n"
else
    puts "no branch! #{branch}\n"
end
```

Outputs "no branch! thisisateststring\n", where 'thisisateststring' is the value that has been assigned to the variable branch earlier in the program. How can it be that the variable `branch` can have a value assigned to it, but not be defined?

Edit:

People seem to not be understanding my question. I am not asking you to figure out why, in this specific instance, the `else` is being executing; I am asking *how can this happen* in general. To put it another way, what code would need to be inserted before this, to cause my case to occur?

As I said, I am new to ruby, so I could easily be misunderstanding something basic. I am not trying to solve a specific problem; I am trying to improve my understanding, by learning more about how ruby works. In this instance, how ruby could output a string, while still thinking it is not defined.

Comment: I don't have the full code. This snippet is my own code, which is being run as part of a bigger framework someone else wrote. I'm just trying to find out how a variable can be defined and not defined at the same time.

Comment: From what I can tell the else statement will never run successfully. Unless perhaps if this code is from a class definition or something similar, then it could be that the second branch call will be handled through the method_missing function.

Comment: After further investigation, I have determined that a symbole :branch is defined elsewhere... is it possible to override the #{} function?

Comment: That problem hasn't reproduced.

Comment: branch is a variable, is it? Because it could be a method instead, of course.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I assumed it was a variable, because I thought that only variables could be used in #{}. Could it be a method? But then, wouldn't a method still be defined? `defined?` returns false...

Comment: I think you need to check again, as defined? does not return false.  Ever.  It returns nil or a description of what the object is in a string.

Comment: @Benubird the method could be undefined, but when you call the method you still might get a string result back depending for some implementations of method_missing. I think, anyway. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@hirolau gave you an example that works. I'd like to reuse his idea and simplify it a little bit for you. Try the following:

```
defined? foo
=> nil

foo
NameError: undefined local variable or method 'foo' for main:Object

def method_missing(m, *params, &block)
   if m.to_s == "foo"
    return "cool stuff"
   end  
end 

# foo is still not defined
defined? foo
=> nil

# but returns some value
foo
=> "cool stuff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, but Ruby has a lot of ways to handle missing methods and undefined variables. Consider for example:

```
class Tree
  def  initialize
    if defined? branch
      p "param: #{branch}\n"
      else
      p "no branch! #{branch}\n"
    end
  end

  def method_missing(method_call)
    return 'this text comes from method_missing'
  end

end

a = Tree.new #=> "no branch! this text comes from method_missing"

class Tree
  def branch
    return 'NOW I HAVE MY OWN METHOD'
  end
end

a = Tree.new #=> "param: NOW I HAVE MY OWN METHOD"
```

Any more info regarding your problem is very hard to give without the context of the statement.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know the context... I'd just like to know any way it is possible.

Comment: Might be something like that, except that your second case is still counting as defined. Could method_mising be doing some sort of lookup?

Comment: Sure, @Abdo's example show you that it really does not need to be defined. I tried to show that just because it is not defined at one point, it could later be defined, thus making the check valid.

Answer (score 0):

The `defined?` Ruby keyword does not check whether a target is nil or not, instead it checks that the target "refers to anything recognizable (literal object, local variable that has been initialized, method name visible from the current scope, etc.)."

Have a look at the documentation to understand its behaviour. http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F

If you want to check if a variable is nil, you can do:

```
if branch.nil? or branch.empty?
    puts "no branch!\n"
else
    puts "param: #{branch}\n"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`defined?` in Ruby is a keyword.

It returns `nil` or a description of what the object is as a string.

In Ruby, the only two things that evaluate to false is `false` and `nil`

So, if the "thing" that you are trying to find out about is undefined, then `defined?` will return `nil` which will evaluate as false in your code, as shown in your question.

To answer your question: "How can a variable have a value and also not be defined?"

It can't.  If it isn't defined as a variable, how could it even be a variable.  But it can be defined as a variable and have a value of `nil`.

Comment: Ok, but it has a value, because my puts call is producing output. Can it have a value of nil, but also a string value?

Comment: What is defined? returning for that?  It likely isn't a variable, then, as a variable can only store one value (an object), just like a method can only return one object.  So the test then, is to `puts defined?(branch) so that you can see what that branch object is.